# Redshift rank() window function based on distinct dimension values and timestamp ordering

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions, rank

I am trying to apply a rank() window function for catching edge cases.

So I have the CTE:

```
with  customer_details_type as 
(
select cd.*, cp.type
from db.ustomer_details as cd
left join db.customer_private as cp on cp.id = cd.customer_id
)
```

I want to the above CTE to add a rank(), that will rank the rows that have different customer_type only, not the ones that have the same. So In the data below I want something like:

[image]

I tried the following:

```
with  customer_details_type as 
(
select cd.*, cp.type, 
, rank() over (partition by  cd.order_id,cd.customer_type order by cd.created desc nulls last) as rank
from db.ustomer_details as cd
left join db.customer_private as cp on cp.id = cd.customer_id
)
```

But it assigned the rank=1 in the order that I am interested to rank.

So the issue I want to solve is: How do I use rank() window function on the order_id partition, for rows that have count(distinct customer_type)>1 only, ordered by the created timestamp?
Can rank() in the above setting do that or would I need to add a second CTE for that task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you want:

```
with customer_details_type as (
      select cd.*, cp.type, 
             dense_rank() over (partition by cd.order_id order by cd.customer_type) as rank
     from db.ustomer_details cd left join
          db.customer_private cp
           on cp.id = cd.customer_id
    )
```

This enumerates the different customer types for each order.

If you actually want them ordered by the first time they appear, then calculate the minimum `created` for each type and use that for ordering:

```
with customer_details_type as (
      select cd.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by cd.order_id order by type_created, customer_type) as rank
      from (select cd.*, cp.type, 
                   min(created) over (partition by cd.order_id, cd.customer_type) as type_created
            from db.customer_details cd left join
                 db.customer_private cp
                 on cp.id = cd.customer_id
           ) cd
    )
```